# Why is my AmChart not updating when new values/orders are added?

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, amcharts

Why is my Amchart not updating when a new order(new data), is added?

Basically what happens now is that whenever another order is made, you will need to refresh the page to see it back into the chart, as opposed to the chart updating live.

```
{{HTML::style('assets/amcharts/style.css')}}
{{ HTML::script('assets/amcharts/amcharts.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('assets/amcharts/serial.js') }}
{{ HTML::script('assets/amcharts/amstock.js') }}
<script type="text/javascript">
var chart;
var defaultLoad=false;

AmCharts.loadJSON=function(timeSpan,buttonClick){
    chartData=[];
    createStockChart();
    var timeSpan_ = '6 hour';
    //console.log('timeSpan:',timeSpan);
    switch(timeSpan){
        case "1DD":
            timeSpan_ = '1 day';
            break;
        case "3DD":
            timeSpan_ = '3 day';
            break;
        case "7DD":
            timeSpan_ = '7 day';
            break;
        case "MAX":
            timeSpan_ = 'MAX';
            break;
        default:
            timeSpan_ = '6 hour';
    }
    console.log('timeSpan_:',timeSpan_);
    $('.loading').show();
    $.ajax({
        url:"<?php echo action('HomeController@getChart')?>",
        type:'post',
        dataType:'json',
        data: {Ajax:1,timeSpan:timeSpan_,market_id:<?php echo $market_id ?>},
        cache:false,
        async:true,
        success:function(rows){ 
            console.log('rows: ',rows);     
            $('.loading').hide();
            for(var i=0; i<rows.length; i++){
                //console.log('chartData '+i+': ',rows[i]);
                var open=parseFloat(rows[i]['open']).toFixed(8);
                var close=parseFloat(rows[i]['close']).toFixed(8);
                var high=parseFloat(rows[i]['high']).toFixed(8);
                var low=parseFloat(rows[i]['low']).toFixed(8);              
                //console.log('rows '+i+' date: '+rows[i]['date']+' open: '+open+' close: '+close+' high: '+high+' low: '+low);
                chartData.push({date:rows[i]['date'],open:open,close:close,high:high,low:low,exchange_volume:rows[i]['exchange_volume']});
            }
            //console.log('chartData: ',chartData);
            //date=rows[rows.length-1]['date'];
            //date=new Date(date.replace(" ","T")+'Z');
            //var localOffset=date.getTimezoneOffset()*60000;
            //date.setTime(date.getTime()+ 600000+ localOffset);
            //chartData.push({date:date,open:rows[rows.length-1]['close'],close:rows[rows.length-1]['close'],high:rows[rows.length-1]['close'],low:rows[rows.length-1]['close'],exchange_volume:0});
            chart.dataProvider=chartData;
            chart.validateNow(); 


            if(buttonClick===false){
                $('input[value="6 hours"]').click();
            }else{
                //$('input[value="MAX"]').removeClass('amChartsButtonSelected').addClass('amChartsButton');
                $('.amChartsPeriodSelector input[type=button]').removeClass('amChartsButtonSelected').addClass('amChartsButton');
                if(timeSpan=='6hh'){
                    $('input[value="6 hours"]').removeClass('amChartsButton').addClass('amChartsButtonSelected');
                }else if(timeSpan=='1DD'){
                    $('input[value="24 hours"]').removeClass('amChartsButton').addClass('amChartsButtonSelected');
                }else if(timeSpan=='3DD'){
                    $('input[value="3 days"]').removeClass('amChartsButton').addClass('amChartsButtonSelected');
                }else if(timeSpan=='7DD'){
                    $('input[value="1 week"]').removeClass('amChartsButton').addClass('amChartsButtonSelected');
                }else{
                    $('input[value="MAX"]').removeClass('amChartsButton').addClass('amChartsButtonSelected');
                }
            }

        }
    });
};
function buttonClickHandler(data){
    console.log('buttonClickHandler:',data);
    if(defaultLoad===true){
        if(typeof data.count!=='undefined'){AmCharts.loadJSON(data.count+ data.predefinedPeriod,true);
        }else{
            AmCharts.loadJSON(data.predefinedPeriod,true);
        }
    }else{
        defaultLoad=true;
    }
}
AmCharts.ready(function(){AmCharts.loadJSON('6hh',false);
    createStockChart();
});
function createStockChart(){
    chart=new AmCharts.AmStockChart();
    chart.pathToImages="/assets/js/amcharts/images/";
    var categoryAxesSettings=new AmCharts.CategoryAxesSettings();
    categoryAxesSettings.minPeriod="10mm";
    categoryAxesSettings.groupToPeriods=["10mm","30mm","hh","3hh","6hh","12hh","DD"];
    chart.categoryAxesSettings=categoryAxesSettings;
    chart.dataDateFormat="YYYY-MM-DD JJ:NN";
    var dataSet=new AmCharts.DataSet();
    dataSet.color="#7f8da9";
    dataSet.fieldMappings=[
        {fromField:"open",toField:"open"},
        {fromField:"close",toField:"close"},
        {fromField:"high",toField:"high"},
        {fromField:"low",toField:"low"},
        {fromField:"exchange_volume",toField:"exchange_volume"}
    ];
    dataSet.dataProvider=chartData;
    dataSet.categoryField="date";
    chart.dataSets=[dataSet];
    var stockPanel1=new AmCharts.StockPanel();
    stockPanel1.showCategoryAxis=false;
    stockPanel1.title="Price";
    stockPanel1.percentHeight=70;
    stockPanel1.numberFormatter={precision:8,decimalSeparator:'.',thousandsSeparator:','};
    var graph1=new AmCharts.StockGraph();
    graph1.valueField="value";
    graph1.type="candlestick";
    graph1.openField="open";
    graph1.closeField="close";
    graph1.highField="high";
    graph1.lowField="low";
    graph1.valueField="close";
    graph1.lineColor="#6bbf46";
    graph1.fillColors="#6bbf46";
    graph1.negativeLineColor="#F87A06";//"#db4c3c";
    graph1.negativeFillColors="#F87A06";//"#db4c3c";
    graph1.fillAlphas=1;
    graph1.balloonText="open:<b>[[open]]</b><br>close:<b>[[close]]</b><br>low:<b>[[low]]</b><br>high:<b>[[high]]</b>";
    graph1.useDataSetColors=false;
    stockPanel1.addStockGraph(graph1);
    var stockLegend1=new AmCharts.StockLegend();
    stockLegend1.valueTextRegular=" ";
    stockLegend1.markerType="none";
    stockPanel1.stockLegend=stockLegend1;
    var stockPanel2=new AmCharts.StockPanel();
    stockPanel2.title="Volume";
    stockPanel2.percentHeight=30;
    stockPanel2.numberFormatter={precision:3,decimalSeparator:'.',thousandsSeparator:','};
    var graph2=new AmCharts.StockGraph();
    graph2.valueField="exchange_volume";
    graph2.type="column";
    graph2.cornerRadiusTop=2;
    graph2.fillAlphas=1;
    graph2.periodValue="Sum";
    stockPanel2.addStockGraph(graph2);
    var stockLegend2=new AmCharts.StockLegend();
    stockLegend2.valueTextRegular=" ";
    stockLegend2.markerType="none";
    stockPanel2.stockLegend=stockLegend2;
    chart.panels=[stockPanel1,stockPanel2];
    var cursorSettings=new AmCharts.ChartCursorSettings();
    cursorSettings.valueBalloonsEnabled=true;
    cursorSettings.fullWidth=true;
    cursorSettings.cursorAlpha=0.1;
    chart.chartCursorSettings=cursorSettings;
    var periodSelector=new AmCharts.PeriodSelector();
    periodSelector.position="top";
    periodSelector.dateFormat="YYYY-MM-DD JJ:NN";
    periodSelector.inputFieldWidth=150;
    periodSelector.inputFieldsEnabled=false;
    periodSelector.hideOutOfScopePeriods=false;
    periodSelector.periods=[
        {period:"hh",count:6,label:"6 hours",selected:true},
        {period:"DD",count:1,label:"24 hours"},
        {period:"DD",count:3,label:"3 days"},
        {period:"DD",count:7,label:"1 week"},
        {period:"MAX",label:"MAX"}
    ];
    periodSelector.addListener('changed',function(period){buttonClickHandler(period);});
    chart.periodSelector=periodSelector;
    var panelsSettings=new AmCharts.PanelsSettings();
    panelsSettings.usePrefixes=false;
    chart.panelsSettings=panelsSettings;
    var valueAxis=new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
    valueAxis.precision=8;
    chart.valueAxis=valueAxis;
    chart.chartScrollbarSettings.enabled=false;
    chart.write('chartdiv');
}

    function use_price(type, price, total_amount){
        // var pre = 'b_';
        // if(type==2) pre = 's_';
        // $('#'+pre+'price').val(price.toFixed(8));
        // $('#'+pre+'amount').val(total_amount.toFixed(8));
        $('#s_price').val(price.toFixed(8));
        $('#s_amount').val(total_amount.toFixed(8));
        $('#b_price').val(price.toFixed(8));
        $('#b_amount').val(total_amount.toFixed(8));
        updateDataSell();
        updateDataBuy();
    } 

</script>
@stop
```

Forgot to include this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('assets/googlechart/jsapi.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('assets/amcharts/amcharts.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset('assets/amcharts/serial.js') }}"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function drawVisualization() {
        var dashboard;
        var chartData=[];
        var timeSpan_ = '1 day';
        var data;
        $.ajax({
            url:"<?php echo action('HomeController@getChart')?>",
            type:'post',
            dataType:'json',
            data: {Ajax:1,timeSpan:timeSpan_,market_id:<?php echo $market_id ?>},
            cache:false,
            async:true,
            success:function(rows){
                //console.log('rows: ',rows);
                $('.loading').hide();
                for(var i=0; i<rows.length; i++){
                    rows[i][0]=new Date(rows[i][0]);
                    //console.log('rows '+i+': ',rows[i][0]);
                    //data.addRow([rows[i][0], '<div class="highcharts-tooltip" zIndex="8" style="cursor:default;padding:0;white-space:nowrap;" visibility="visible" transform="translate(570,40)" opacity="1">Hellllocccccccc</div>', rows[i][1], rows[i][2], rows[i][3], rows[i][4], rows[i][5]]);
                }
                //console.log('data: ',data);
                data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(rows, true);


                var rCandlestickChart  = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
                    chartType: 'ComboChart',//'CandlestickChart',
                    containerId: 'chart_div',
                    options: {
                            height: 300,
                            fontName: '"Open Sans", "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif',
                            backgroundColor: "transparent",
                            chartArea: {height: "70%", width: "90%"},
                            hAxis: {slantedText: !1, minTextSpacing: "40", maxAlternation: 1},
                            vAxis: {format: "#,#####0.00000"},
                            legend: 'none',//{position: "none"},
                            tooltip: {isHtml: true},
                            seriesType: "bars",
                            series: {
                                0: {
                                    type: "candlesticks",
                                    targetAxisIndex: 0,
                                    color: "black",
                                    candlestick: {
                                        fallingColor: {
                                            fill: "#0ab92b",
                                            stroke: "green",
                                            color: "green",
                                            strokeWidth: 1
                                        },
                                        risingColor: {
                                            fill: "#f01717",
                                            stroke: "#d91e1e",
                                            color: "#d91e1e",
                                            strokeWidth: 1
                                        }
                                    }
                                },
                                1: {
                                    type: "bars",
                                    targetAxisIndex:1,
                                    color:"#4EBDE7"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                });

                var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
                    controlType: 'ChartRangeFilter',
                    containerId: 'control_div',
                    options: {
                        filterColumnIndex: 0,
                        ui: {
                            chartType: "ComboChart",
                            backgroundColor: {fill: "transparent"},
                            chartOptions: {
                                fontName: '"Open Sans", "Lucida Grande", Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif',
                                backgroundColor: {fill: "transparent"},
                                height: 70,
                                chartArea: {width: "90%", backgroundColor: {fill: "transparent"}, height: 50},
                                seriesType: "bars",
                                series: {
                                    0: {
                                        targetAxisIndex: 1,
                                        type: "bars",
                                        color: "#4b71a2",
                                        hAxis: {baselineColor: "none"}
                                    }
                                },
                                hAxis: {
                                    baselineColor: "none",
                                    textPosition: "out",
                                    textStyle: {color: "#ddd"},
                                    format: "yyyy.MM.dd"
                                }
                            },
                            minRangeSize: 216e5
                        }
                    }
                });
                dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(document.querySelector('#dashboard_div'));
                dashboard.bind([control], [rCandlestickChart]);
                dashboard.draw(data);

                function zoomLastDay () {
                    $('.chart-filter').removeClass('active');
                    $('#lastDay').addClass('active');
                    var range = data.getColumnRange(0);
                    //console.log('zoomLastDay range: ',range);
                    control.setState({
                        range: {
                            start: new Date(range.max.getFullYear(), range.max.getMonth(), range.max.getDate() - 1),
                            end: range.max
                        }
                    });
                    $.ajax({
                        url:"<?php echo action('HomeController@getChart')?>",
                        type:'post',
                        dataType:'json',
                        data: {Ajax:1,timeSpan:'1 day',market_id:<?php echo $market_id ?>},
                        cache:false,
                        async:true,
                        success:function(rows){
                            for(var i=0; i<rows.length; i++){
                                rows[i][0]=new Date(rows[i][0]);
                            }
                            //console.log('zoomLastDay range rows: ',rows);
                            var data1 = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(rows, true);
                            dashboard.draw(data1);
                            control.draw();
                        }
                    });
```

~~~~~~~~

Am i invoking chart.validateNow incorrectly?

If so, what would be the correct way to call it?

EDIT:

```
{{HTML::style('assets/amcharts/style.css')}}
    {{ HTML::script('assets/amcharts/amcharts.js') }}
    {{ HTML::script('assets/amcharts/serial.js') }}
    {{ HTML::script('assets/amcharts/amstock.js') }}
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var chart;
    var defaultLoad=false;

    AmCharts.loadJSON=function(timeSpan,buttonClick){
        chartData=[];
                var timeSpan_ = '6 hour';
        //console.log('timeSpan:',timeSpan);
        switch(timeSpan){
            case "1DD":
                timeSpan_ = '1 day';
                break;
            case "3DD":
                timeSpan_ = '3 day';
                break;
            case "7DD":
                timeSpan_ = '7 day';
                break;
            case "MAX":
                timeSpan_ = 'MAX';
                break;
            default:
                timeSpan_ = '6 hour';
        }
        console.log('timeSpan_:',timeSpan_);
        $('.loading').show();
        $.ajax({
            url:"<?php echo action('HomeController@getChart')?>",
            type:'post',
            dataType:'json',
            data: {Ajax:1,timeSpan:timeSpan_,market_id:<?php echo $market_id ?>},
            cache:false,
            async:true,
            success:function(rows){ 
                console.log('rows: ',rows);     
                $('.loading').hide();
                for(var i=0; i<rows.length; i++){
                    //console.log('chartData '+i+': ',rows[i]);
                    var open=parseFloat(rows[i]['open']).toFixed(8);
                    var close=parseFloat(rows[i]['close']).toFixed(8);
                    var high=parseFloat(rows[i]['high']).toFixed(8);
                    var low=parseFloat(rows[i]['low']).toFixed(8);              
                    //console.log('rows '+i+' date: '+rows[i]['date']+' open: '+open+' close: '+close+' high: '+high+' low: '+low);
                    chartData.push({date:rows[i]['date'],open:open,close:close,high:high,low:low,exchange_volume:rows[i]['exchange_volume']});
                }
                //console.log('chartData: ',chartData);
                //date=rows[rows.length-1]['date'];
                //date=new Date(date.replace(" ","T")+'Z');
                //var localOffset=date.getTimezoneOffset()*60000;
                //date.setTime(date.getTime()+ 600000+ localOffset);
                //chartData.push({date:date,open:rows[rows.length-1]['close'],close:rows[rows.length-1]['close'],high:rows[rows.length-1]['close'],low:rows[rows.length-1]['close'],exchange_volume:0});
                chart.dataSets[0].dataProvider = chartData;
                chart.validateNow(true, false); 


                if(buttonClick===false){
                    $('input[value="6 hours"]').click();
                }else{
                    //$('input[value="MAX"]').removeClass('amChartsButtonSelected').addClass('amChartsButton');
                    $('.amChartsPeriodSelector input[type=button]').removeClass('amChartsButtonSelected').addClass('amChartsButton');
                    if(timeSpan=='6hh'){
                        $('input[value="6 hours"]').removeClass('amChartsButton').addClass('amChartsButtonSelected');
                    }else if(timeSpan=='1DD'){
                        $('input[value="24 hours"]').removeClass('amChartsButton').addClass('amChartsButtonSelected');
                    }else if(timeSpan=='3DD'){
                        $('input[value="3 days"]').removeClass('amChartsButton').addClass('amChartsButtonSelected');
                    }else if(timeSpan=='7DD'){
                        $('input[value="1 week"]').removeClass('amChartsButton').addClass('amChartsButtonSelected');
                    }else{
                        $('input[value="MAX"]').removeClass('amChartsButton').addClass('amChartsButtonSelected');
                    }
                }

            }
        });
    };
    function buttonClickHandler(data){
        console.log('buttonClickHandler:',data);
        if(defaultLoad===true){
            if(typeof data.count!=='undefined'){AmCharts.loadJSON(data.count+ data.predefinedPeriod,true);
            }else{
                AmCharts.loadJSON(data.predefinedPeriod,true);
            }
        }else{
            defaultLoad=true;
        }
    }
    AmCharts.ready(function(){AmCharts.loadJSON('6hh',false);
            });
    function createStockChart(){
        chart=new AmCharts.AmStockChart();
        chart.pathToImages="/assets/js/amcharts/images/";
        var categoryAxesSettings=new AmCharts.CategoryAxesSettings();
        categoryAxesSettings.minPeriod="10mm";
        categoryAxesSettings.groupToPeriods=["10mm","30mm","hh","3hh","6hh","12hh","DD"];
        chart.categoryAxesSettings=categoryAxesSettings;
        chart.dataDateFormat="YYYY-MM-DD JJ:NN";
        var dataSet=new AmCharts.DataSet();
        dataSet.color="#7f8da9";
        dataSet.fieldMappings=[
            {fromField:"open",toField:"open"},
            {fromField:"close",toField:"close"},
            {fromField:"high",toField:"high"},
            {fromField:"low",toField:"low"},
            {fromField:"exchange_volume",toField:"exchange_volume"}
        ];
        dataSet.dataProvider=chartData;
        dataSet.categoryField="date";
        chart.dataSets=[dataSet];
        var stockPanel1=new AmCharts.StockPanel();
        stockPanel1.showCategoryAxis=false;
        stockPanel1.title="Price";
        stockPanel1.percentHeight=70;
        stockPanel1.numberFormatter={precision:8,decimalSeparator:'.',thousandsSeparator:','};
        var graph1=new AmCharts.StockGraph();
        graph1.valueField="value";
        graph1.type="candlestick";
        graph1.openField="open";
        graph1.closeField="close";
        graph1.highField="high";
        graph1.lowField="low";
        graph1.valueField="close";
        graph1.lineColor="#6bbf46";
        graph1.fillColors="#6bbf46";
        graph1.negativeLineColor="#F87A06";//"#db4c3c";
        graph1.negativeFillColors="#F87A06";//"#db4c3c";
        graph1.fillAlphas=1;
        graph1.balloonText="open:<b>[[open]]</b><br>close:<b>[[close]]</b><br>low:<b>[[low]]</b><br>high:<b>[[high]]</b>";
        graph1.useDataSetColors=false;
        stockPanel1.addStockGraph(graph1);
        var stockLegend1=new AmCharts.StockLegend();
        stockLegend1.valueTextRegular=" ";
        stockLegend1.markerType="none";
        stockPanel1.stockLegend=stockLegend1;
        var stockPanel2=new AmCharts.StockPanel();
        stockPanel2.title="Volume";
        stockPanel2.percentHeight=30;
        stockPanel2.numberFormatter={precision:3,decimalSeparator:'.',thousandsSeparator:','};
        var graph2=new AmCharts.StockGraph();
        graph2.valueField="exchange_volume";
        graph2.type="column";
        graph2.cornerRadiusTop=2;
        graph2.fillAlphas=1;
        graph2.periodValue="Sum";
        stockPanel2.addStockGraph(graph2);
        var stockLegend2=new AmCharts.StockLegend();
        stockLegend2.valueTextRegular=" ";
        stockLegend2.markerType="none";
        stockPanel2.stockLegend=stockLegend2;
        chart.panels=[stockPanel1,stockPanel2];
        var cursorSettings=new AmCharts.ChartCursorSettings();
        cursorSettings.valueBalloonsEnabled=true;
        cursorSettings.fullWidth=true;
        cursorSettings.cursorAlpha=0.1;
        chart.chartCursorSettings=cursorSettings;
        var periodSelector=new AmCharts.PeriodSelector();
        periodSelector.position="top";
        periodSelector.dateFormat="YYYY-MM-DD JJ:NN";
        periodSelector.inputFieldWidth=150;
        periodSelector.inputFieldsEnabled=false;
        periodSelector.hideOutOfScopePeriods=false;
        periodSelector.periods=[
            {period:"hh",count:6,label:"6 hours",selected:true},
            {period:"DD",count:1,label:"24 hours"},
            {period:"DD",count:3,label:"3 days"},
            {period:"DD",count:7,label:"1 week"},
            {period:"MAX",label:"MAX"}
        ];
        periodSelector.addListener('changed',function(period){buttonClickHandler(period);});
        chart.periodSelector=periodSelector;
        var panelsSettings=new AmCharts.PanelsSettings();
        panelsSettings.usePrefixes=false;
        chart.panelsSettings=panelsSettings;
        var valueAxis=new AmCharts.ValueAxis();
        valueAxis.precision=8;
        chart.valueAxis=valueAxis;
        chart.chartScrollbarSettings.enabled=false;
        chart.write('chartdiv');
    }

        function use_price(type, price, total_amount){
            // var pre = 'b_';
            // if(type==2) pre = 's_';
            // $('#'+pre+'price').val(price.toFixed(8));
            // $('#'+pre+'amount').val(total_amount.toFixed(8));
            $('#s_price').val(price.toFixed(8));
            $('#s_amount').val(total_amount.toFixed(8));
            $('#b_price').val(price.toFixed(8));
            $('#b_amount').val(total_amount.toFixed(8));
            updateDataSell();
            updateDataBuy();
        } 

    </script>
    @stop
```

I've updated the code to this, but it's still not updating the chart with new data.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your code:

1) Don't recreate the chart every time you're updating it. You only need to call `createStockChart()` once. Calling it multiple times will consume resources as it will create another chart instance and each instance will try to overrule each other in the same div, so you need to remove it from your `loadJSON` method.

2) The stock chart's dataProvider is stored in a dataset object, unlike the other chart types. Instead of `chart.dataProvider = chartData;`, you want `chart.dataSets[0].dataProivder = chartData;` since you only have one dataSet.

3) `validateData()` is more appropriate for data updates, whereas `validateNow()` is typically used for visual changes. Sometimes calling both is necessary, but the former can usually handle both cases without any additional flags. Switching to `validateData()` or calling [`validateNow(true, false)`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptstockchart/AmChart#validateNow) will redraw the chart with your changes, provided you set the dataProvider correctly (see #2).

**Edit** - [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jc5ua7u7/20/). Added `zoomOut` to prevent the data from zooming in too much on smaller periods.

Comment: Updated the code as suggested, problem still exists. I still have to manually refresh for the chart to change.

Comment: I said to remove `createStockChart` from `loadJSON`. Don't remove it from `AmCharts.ready` unless you are calling createStockChart elsewhere. I made a fiddle of your latest update with a mock update method and adding `createStockChart` back to `AmCharts.ready` and it works for me: https://jsfiddle.net/jc5ua7u7/18/. Check your console or modify the fiddle such that it reproduces the problem you're having.

Comment: Will do in  a bit.